# Replace String Between Two Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a serious problem about indexing in array. I've been working on this for 2 days and couldn't find answer yet.

I want to do that, search specific character in array then replace it with other string. I'm using **replaceObjectAtIndex** method but my code is doesn't work.

Here is my code;

```
    NSString *commentText = commentTextView.text;
    NSUInteger textLength = [commentText length];
    NSString *atSign = @"@";
    NSMutableArray *commentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [commentArray addObject:commentText];

    for (int arrayCounter=1; arrayCounter<=textLength; arrayCounter++)
    {
        NSRange isRange = [commentText rangeOfString:atSign options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(isRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            commentText = [commentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:commentText withString:atSign];
            [_mentionsearch filtrele:_mentionText];
            id<textSearchProtocol> delegate;
            [delegate closeList:[[self.searchResult valueForKey:@"user_name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }
```

Ok, now i can find "@" sign in the text and i can match it. But this is the source of problem that, i can not replace any string with "@" sign. Here is the last part of code;

```
    -(void)closeList
    {
        NSArray *arrayWithSign = [commentTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSMutableArray *arrayCopy = [arrayWithSign mutableCopy];
        [arrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:isRange.location withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",username]];
    }
```

When im logging **isRange.location** value, it returns correct. But when im try to run, my application is crashing. So, i can not replacing **[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",username]** parameter. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: How is it crashing? You have to include the crash log.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a range taken from a string search as the index into an array?

Comment: There is no log downside. Only thing i have, (lldb) 0x6ae8952:jae    0x6ae8962 ; __pthread_kill + 26.

Comment: In `NSRange isRange = [commentText rangeOfString:atSign options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];` and in `[arrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:isRange.location withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",username]];` variable `isRange` is same?

Comment: Try this to remove @ from string     NSString *replacedstr=[YourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];

Comment: Are you getting crash in stringWithFormat method in the last line of your code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change a substring in a string with a new string. In this case, why don't you use directly the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method of NSString:

```
NSString *stringToBeChanged = @"...";
NSString *stringToBeChangedWith = @"...";
NSString *commentTextNew = [commentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToBeChanged withString:stringToBeChangedWith];
```

Comment: I did big mistake about array results. That is solution thx :)

Comment: i want to change the string in between "<>"    <my stirng>  to  < new tring> 
my string is they dynamic string then how can i identify the string